# Confidence Intervals and Hyptothesis testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, inference

Iam currently reading up on basic statistics and Iam somewhat confused about the computation/inference of confidence intervals and hypothesis tests.
As far as I have understood there are several techniques for both confidence interval estimation and hypothesis testing:

confidence interval are computed:

- estimate +- margin of error **or**
- bootstrapping

hypothesis testing is performed by:

- parametric tests (for nearly normal distributed data) or non-parametric test **or**
- permutation (often in combination with bootstrapping)

When do I have to use which method? Does it depend on the sample size?

Thanks in advance for any help,

cheers,

Michael

Comment: A few points on the premises in your question: (**1**) While there is a relationship, confidence intervals and tests have quite different purposes - e.g. note that a test has a rejection rule, a CI does not. (**2**) It's very common for a CI to *not* consist of an estimate $\pm$ some margin (consider an interval for a variance, for example, or a small sample interval for a correlation, or see many of the intervals [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval)). (**3**) [Parametric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_statistics) does *not* imply "normal" --

Comment: (**4**) permutation tests and bootstrap tests (bootstrapping is more general than just testing) are both resampling procedures but in simple cases where both apply one resamples 'with replacement' (so typically about a third of the data is not present in a given resample) and one without replacement (so all of the data reappear each time). Note also that typically one is 'exact' and the other is not. They are distinct things.

Comment: Hi and thanks for tour comments regarding my question!

I just got confused about that there a different method for in example computing the confidence interval.

If one would take the confidence interval of a mean as an example:
I could use a T-distribution to compute the confidence interval using the standard error, or I could use bootstrapping.